# Display Outlook calendar on form?

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting

I'm trying to load my calendar into something on my form, preferably a label or listbox or anything that cannot be edited. I'm able to load it in CLI but i'm unsure of how to process it, please may someone help?

Ideally I'd like for it to have the date at the top (optional), then have a row display the start time and subject.

Many Thanks
Sam

```
add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
# Calendar = olFolderCalendar = 9
$calendar = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9)
# get today's calendar items!
$calendar.Items | Where-Object {$_.Start -ge $(Get-Date) -and $_.Start -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(1)} | select Start, subject
```

If I try and turn it into a string variable, the output I get is System.__ComObject repeatedly

```
$StrCalendar = $calendar.Items
$textfieldcal.text = $StrCalendar
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Add your calendar items to a variable, then you can access each one in a Foreach loop.  $cItems = $calendar.Items | Where-Object {$_.Start -ge $(Get-Date) -and $_.Start -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(1)} | select Start, subject.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i'm really new to this!